# Unmatched records

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables where i want to display the Id which are present in the MBA table but which are not held in the PIX table

PIX

```
 Id Channel Product ProgDate    ProgStartTime   ProgEndTime 
    2   PIX Parachute Advansed  2011-04-02  18:00:00.0000000    01:00:00.0000000
    5   PIX Parachute Advansed  2011-04-02  18:00:00.0000000    01:00:00.0000000
    6   PIX Parachute Advansed  2011-04-02  23:00:00.0000000    01:00:00.0000000
```

MBA

```
mbaID   Channel Product-MAP Progdate-MAP    AdvTime 
2   PIX Parachute Advansed  4/2/11  19:54:56
3   PIX Parachute Advansed  4/2/11  19:15:59
4   PIX Parachute Advansed  4/2/11  22:26:28
5   PIX Parachute Advansed  4/2/11  21:47:01
6   PIX Parachute Advansed  4/3/11  0:31:08
7   PIX Parachute Advansed  4/3/11  0:17:23
```

I need columns of 3 , 4 and  7 to be displayed.
But when i perform JOin it gives me duplicates.
Please help

Comment: Care to tag the which RDBMS you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` the table `MBA` with `IS NULL` predicate to display only those rows that has no entries in the other table `PIX`. Something like:

```
SELECT MBA.*
FROM MBA 
LEFT JOIN PIX ON MBA.mbaID = pix.id
WHERE pix.Id IS NULL;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2fd6/1)

This will give you the rows with the ids 3, 4, 7:

```
| MBAID | CHANNEL | PRODUCTMAP | PROGDATEMAP |                      ADVTIME |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     3 |     PIX |  Parachute |    Advansed | April, 02 1911 21:15:59+0000 |
|     4 |     PIX |  Parachute |    Advansed | April, 03 1911 00:26:28+0000 |
|     7 |     PIX |  Parachute |    Advansed | April, 03 1911 02:17:23+0000 |
```

---

You can also use the `NOT IN` predicate instead of `JOIN`:

```
SELECT MBA.*
FROM MBA 
WHERE mbaid NOT IN(SELECT id
                   FROM PIX 
                   WHERE id IS NOT NULL);
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2fd6/2)

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUBQUERY`

```
select distinct mbaid from mba where mbaid not in (select distinct id from pix)
```

Using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
select distinct mbaid from mba,pix where mba.mbaid=pix.id(+) and pix.id is null;
```